# React pass props to onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering . Is it possible to use `onChange` event handler , and pass props to the method as parameters ?

For example :

```
    <TablePagination
          ....
          onChangePage={props.setBrokersListPage}
        />
```

The method `setBrokersListPage` automatically gets `event` and `page` objects . I want to pass an additional prop as a parameter  . Something like

```
          onChangePage={props.setBrokersListPage(props.otherParam)}
```

And the otherParam will be the third param of `setBrokerListPage`  .  Is it possible ?

I tried using [@omri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51966712/5992977) answer but the default passed params are getting broken . Page is not recognized any more if I do this :

setBrokersListPage :

```
export const setBrokersListPage = (event, page,brokersListFilter) => {
    return getBrokers(page,brokersListFilter)  
}
```

And `onChangePage` :

```
onChangePage={() => props.setBrokersListPage(props.brokersListFilter)}
```

Comment: yes possible. Then you need to define the `setBrokersListPage` function that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your funcation so that on getting some arguments it can return another function like this.

```
setBrokersListPage = (args) => (event) => {
    // logic with args, event
}
```

Now do like:

```
onChangePae={props.setBrokersListPage(props.otherParam)}
```

Comment: After I do this , `otherParam` is stored inside args ? I also need `page` value with `event`

Comment: @Yossi Yes it will be there.

Comment: I tried, I can't access the `page` element any more .. I tried `(args) => (event,page) =>..` but when loging event and page it seems wrong .. ( I only need to use the page, not the event element )

Comment: look the change handler will give you only event.. other argument you need to collect...

Comment: But when I use onChange event like I mentioned in the question the page is being passed automatically . How do I collect the page ?

Comment: from where you get the page?

Comment: It's being passed automatically from onChangePage event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178535/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-yossi).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can reach it by passing it as a function:

```
onChangePage={() => props.setBrokersListPage(props.otherParam)}
```

Or, instead of rendering a new function each time, you can do:

```
setBrokersListPage = () => {
    props.setBrokersListPage(props.otherParam)
}

onChangePage={this.setBrokersListPage}
```

Comment: Unfortenutly this doesn't work.. The default passed values are getting broken. Now the page param is being passed as undefined ..